# 'state' is not defined (no-undef)

Tags: react-native, state, jsx

I am complete noob and am just following a tutorial in react-native on udemy.   However, I have reached a wall and cannot find a solution anywhere?

Currently I am getting an error from ESLint showing that state is undefined.

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {
 state = { albums: [] };   //state is underlined

  ComponentWillMount() {
     axios.get('https:/rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
      .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
   }

    renderAlbums() {

     render() {
console.log(this.state);
return (
<View>
  {this.renderAlbums()}
 </View>
  **strong text**);
 }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

Has there been any update regarding defining 'state' in React-Native?

Sincerely appreciate the help!

Comment: replace `ComponentWillMount` with `componentWillMount` and `render` is unique to component

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Could possibly provide some quick sample code?

Comment: check the [link](https://snack.expo.io/BkShZyt2z)

Comment: I had a look at the code and also copied and pasted it but am still getting the same error?      I am running axios@0.18.0 on MAC if that helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.state = { 
            albums: [] 
        };
        this.renderAlbums = this.renderAlbums.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
         axios.get('https:/rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
          .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
    }

    renderAlbums() {
        return (
            <View /> // return your Albums here as you need
        );
    }

     render() {
         return (
            <View>
              {this.renderAlbums()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}


export default AlbumList;
```